# search between two column dates of the same table in yii2 Active record

Tags: mysql, yii2

I am trying to search a input date from user between two date columns in the same table. There is a start_date and end_date in the table ifndb.schedule stored in MySQL database. I am able run the query in MySQL Schema as follows:

```
 Select * from ifndb.schedule WHERE date(2017-10-15') BETWEEN start_date and end_date;
```

But how to search the above query in Yii2 Active Record ?

Comment: $model = ModelName::find()
->where(['between', 'date', "start date", "end date" ])->all();

Comment: your sql is wrong, you are missing single cote near date, it should be "Select * from ifndb.schedule WHERE date('2017-10-15') BETWEEN start_date and end_date;"

Comment: @RajeshPradhan sorry missed out the code while typing.

Comment: @tharif thanks for your immediate reply. I am getting unknown column 'date' in 'where clause' while passing the query. Appreciate if you could let me know how to pass $model in $query ->andFilterWhere().

Comment: Does your query posted " Select * from ifndb.schedule WHERE date(2017-10-15') BETWEEN start_date and end_date;" fetch output who want ?

Comment: @tharif Becoz 'between' is not helping, I am trying to pass the query like this ->andFilterWhere(['AND', ['>=', 'start_date', $this->enter_date],['<=', 'end_date', $this->enter_date]]); I am getting 0 result. Pl. note that $this->enter_date is from user.

Comment: your query fetching required result in MySQL schema ?

Comment: My table is like this start_date of user1 is 16-10-2017 and end_date of the same user1 is 20-10-2017 in the table ifndb.schedule. the same way start_date of the user2 is 26-10-2017 and end_date of the user2 is 09-11-2017. while filtering the customer is passing one input date to filter from user1,user2,user3..... suppose the customer is looking for schedule by giving 18-10-2017 the result should throw User1's data from the table

Comment: @tharif - your query fetching required result in MySQL schema ? – Yes "Select * from ifndb.schedule WHERE date('2017-10-15') BETWEEN start_date and end_date;" is fetching the data in MySql schema but in Yii2 i am not finding the right query and how to pass and filter the data.

Comment: @at_ram give a try :    $test = (new \yii\db\Query())
      ->select(['column'])
      ->from('schedule_tab')
      ->where(['between', 'ur_input_date_var', 'start_date', 'end_date'])
      ->all();
   var_dump($test);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try this Query

```
$query=ModelName::find()->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'start_date',$this->date])->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'end_date',$this->date])->all();
```

Comment: I am trying to do this... My table is like this start_date of user1 is 16-10-2017 and end_date of the same user1 is 20-10-2017 in the table ifndb.schedule. the same way start_date of the user2 is 26-10-2017 and end_date of the user2 is 09-11-2017. while filtering the customer is passing one input date to filter from user1,user2,user3..... suppose the customer is looking for schedule by giving 18-10-2017 the result should throw User1's data from the table.

Comment: is there two field ? start_date and end_date

Comment: yes there are two field start_date and end_date in table ifndb.schedule.

Comment: -Got the result. But It is strange the result is fetching when I give <= start_date and >= end_date. i edited your code and passed it like this  ->andFilterwhere(['AND',[ '>=', 'end_date',$this->date],['<=', 'start_date',$this->date]])->all();

Comment: you can also use ->andFilterWhere([ '>=', 'end_date',$this->date])->andFilterWhere([ '<=', 'start_date',$this->date]);

Comment: It works. many thanks. But is the condition we are passing right method like <=start_date and >=end_date ? becoz the start_date is >= the given date always isnt?

Answer (score -1):

I always work with this.Hope it can help

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
                ->select(['username', 'email'])
                ->from('user')
                ->where(['between', 'created_at', 1496725846, 1498568303])
                ->limit(10)
                ->all();
                var_dump($rows);
```

**Explanation: of** `->where(['between', 'created_at', 1496725846, 1498568303])`
the query will return email and username where create_date is BETWEEN   *1496725846* and *1498568303*

Comment: yii2 'between' works for two input range from one column name 'created_at'. What i am looking is one input date($this->enter_date) to search  between two column dates start_date & end_date of the same table.